# Why does script.src work as it does?

Tags: javascript, browser

I couldn't find any documentation or specification regarding `src` attribute of `script` tag.

Browsers manipulate a value of this attribute that it always reflects [absolute URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-27). Let's consider a following example:

domain: `https://example.com`

script tag: `<script src="/path/a/b/c.js"></script>`

```
script.getAttribute("src")
> /path/a/b/c.js
```

```
script.src
> https://example.com/path/a/b/c.js
```

As you can see there's difference between `src` and `getAttribute("src")`.

I'd like to know where I can find details about it (documentation / specification / source code of browser's implementation).

What is the support of this feature among browsers (including mobile)?

Comment: If you want a link to the source code of your browser, you'll have to tell us what your browser is. But then if you know what your browser is called then a simple Google search should do.

Comment: I finally found this behavior in the HTML5 specification and added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it in the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflect):

First there's [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) that discusses the `.src` property for a `<script>` tag:

> The IDL attributes src, type, charset, defer, each must reflect the
>   respective content attributes of the same name.

Then, if you follow a [link in that specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflect) to see what "reflect" means, you get to this:

> If a reflecting IDL attribute is a DOMString attribute whose content
>   attribute is defined to contain a URL, then on getting, the IDL
>   attribute must resolve the value of the content attribute relative to
>   the element and return the resulting **absolute URL** if that was
>   successful, or the empty string otherwise; and on setting, must set
>   the content attribute to the specified literal value. If the content
>   attribute is absent, the IDL attribute must return the default value,
>   if the content attribute has one, or else the empty string.

So, to describe this in a little brief form:  If you set the `.src` property (or any other property that takes a URL), then exactly what you set is stored as the property.  When you get the `.src` property, the value returned is the resulting absolute URL after the property has been resolved relative to the base URL.

As for `.getAttribute()`, the specification for that is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9).  It just says:

> Retrieves an attribute value by name.
>
> Return Value
>
> DOMString | The Attr value as a string, or the empty string if that attribute 
>   does not have a specified or default value.

Notably absent from this description is anything related to the special behavior that URL attributes have when reading their property directly as describe above.  Thus, using `.getAttribute()` does not have that special "reflect" behavior.  It just returns the raw value of the attribute with no special `getter` behavior.

---

This is an intended behavior and has been this way for a long time.  There are also specific developer websites for particular browsers that describe the behavior.

Reading the `.src` property always returns a fully qualified URL, regardless of what you assigned in the HTML or via Javascript.

Reading that same property with `.getAttribute("src")` returns exactly what was in the HTML.

Microsoft documents how IE behaves in this regard for any tag that has a URI as a property starting with IE8 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347148(v=vs.85).aspx).

Mozilla documents how Firefox behaves in this regard for images [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

Demo for images (though all types of tags that have a `src` or `href` property appear to have the same behavior (including `<script>` tags):

```js
var t = document.getElementById("target");
log("target.getAttribute('src') = ", target.getAttribute('src'));
log("target.src = ", target.src);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://files.the-friend-family.com/log.js"></script>
  <base href="http://dummyimage.com">
</head>
<img id="target" src="/200x100/000/fff">
```

In fact, here's a little utility that takes advantage of this fact:

```js
function makeAbsolute(uri) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = uri;
    return a.href;
}

var x = makeAbsolute("test.html");
document.write(x);
```

Comment: Finally found the reference to this behavior in the HTML5 specification.  Added that to the start of my answer.

Comment: Great research. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With regards to `<script src="...">` specifically, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) makes no mention of the `src` property having to return the fully qualified URI.

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) addresses only the `src` attribute:

> The **src** attribute, if specified, gives the address of the external script resource to use. The value of the attribute must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces identifying a script resource of the type given by the `type` attribute, if the attribute is present, or of the type "`text/javascript`", if the attribute is absent. A resource is a script resource of a given type if that type identifies a scripting language and the resource conforms with the requirements of that language's specification.

Nevertheless, I have checked that Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all implement the behavior you mentioned.

---

In general, there is a difference between element attributes and properties, and the two don't necessarily have to agree.

#### Attributes

Without diving too far into the spec, an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) instance maintains a [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) collection, which holds the **DOM attributes** on the node. For example, the following element

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

has an `id` attribute with the value `"test"`. Note that attribute names and values are always strings (more precisely, `DOMString`s).

Attributes can be accessed using `element.getAttribute(name)`.

#### Properties

Additionally, an `Element` instance, just like any JavaScript object, has a set of properties which are accessible directly on the instance. For example, `innerHTML` is a property.

Properties can be accessed simply using the dot notation, i.e. `element.innerHTML`. They are allowed to have getters and setters.

---

In the case of the `<script>` element (instance of `HTMLScriptElement`), there is both `src` property, and a `src` attribute. Observe:

```js
// check out the descriptor of the src property
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, 'src').get);

var script = document.createElement('script');
console.log(script.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(script.src);

script.src = 'test.js';
console.log(script.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(script.src);

script.setAttribute('src', 'foo.js');
console.log(script.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(script.src);
```

Output (Chrome 47):

```
function () { [native code] }
null

test.js
http://stacksnippets.net/test.js
foo.js
http://stacksnippets.net/foo.js
```

Accessing the `src` **property** on the element invokes the getter for that property, which returns the fully qualified URL. Retrieving the `src` **attribute** returns whatever string you set there as-is, or `null` if the attribute has not yet been set.